# How to scale/rotate vertexes/edges/faces around a point in 3DS Max?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max, modeling

When using Blender, you have a "3d cursor", that you can put it on a location and then make an operation like scale and rotate around that point. Can
I do the same in 3DS Max?

When that point is placed on one corner of an edge, that corner remains stationary while the other corner is scaling/rotating. For the polygons it is the same way.

How can I do something like that in 3DS Max?

For scaling -

- From this -

[image]

- To this -

[image]

For rotation -

- From this -

[image]

- To this -

[image]

Comment: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/3ds-Max-3ds-Max-Design-General/Q-Rotate-around-mouse-cursor/td-p/3997568

Comment: Thanks. If I red correctly - The oparation can be done only around an object;. How can I make the scaling/rotation to be done around a vertex/edge/polygon? And can I rotate individual vertices/edges/polygons (maybe the link explains it, but English is not my native language so it confused me a little)? 
     

Even if it is using an object, can I center it on an vertex/edge/polygon?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using a dummy helper.

E.g. you've got an object and want to rotate some polygons:

[image: Creating shape]
[image: Estimate what should be done]

Go to helpers Create -> Helpers -> Dummy (via sidebar or main menu)

Select it, pick the Move tool, activate vertex snaps, and drag it to the point (vertex, edge, etc.) you want to turn polygons around:

[image: Prepare dummy]
[image: Place dummy]

Turn off snaps. Then go to sublevel of your object, select edges, lock selection (space bar).

Select the tool you need, say Rotation, Pick reference coordinate system, click on Dummy, use Transform coordinate center.

To scale first click on axis you need then click and drag (using 3dsmax 2020)

[image]

Finally you can Rotate it around the required point, as well as scale
[image]
[image]